# Firebase Cloud Functions callable functions Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Firebase CLI version: 12.4.0

Firebase Unity version: 11.2.0 (latest)

Unity: 2022.2.17

According to my understanding of firebase callable functions are that Firebase SDK automatically passes the `context` as parameter, but on server in my case auth is undefined and giving the following error

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')
    at /workspace/index.js:17:16
    at fixedLen (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/https.js:118:31)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:467:32
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

`index.js`

```js
    const {onRequest, onCall, HttpsError} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
    const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");

    initializeApp();

    exports.onLoginAddOTPEntry = onCall((data, context) => {
      console.log(data.otp);
      console.log(data.email);
      console.log(context);
    
      if (!data || !data.email || !data.otp) {
        throw new HttpsError("invalid-argument",
            "onLoginAddOTPEntry should be called with email and otp");
      }
    
      if (!context.auth) {
        throw new HttpsError(
            "unauthorized",
            "User is not authenticated",
        );
      }

      return "Worked!";
    });
```

Further debugging found out `data` and `context`, both are `undefined` somehow, while in Unity I debugged and logged the data is passed as it should be. Also, the user is logged in too. Here is my Unity C# calling code

```cs
private FirebaseFunctions firebaseFunctions;

public void Initialize()
{
    firebaseFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
}

public async void CallableFunction(string functionName,
    KeyValuePair<string, string>[] dataToPass,
    Action<bool, string, string> _onSuccess)
{
    var function = firebaseFunctions.GetHttpsCallable(functionName);

    // pass data
    if (dataToPass?.Length > 0)
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        for (int i = 0, count = dataToPass.Length; i < count; ++i)
        {
            data.Add(dataToPass[i].Key, dataToPass[i].Value);
        }

        await function.CallAsync(data).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Task: " + task.ToJSON());
        });
        return;
    }

    await function.CallAsync().ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
         Debug.Log("Task: " + task.ToJSON());
    });
}
```

NOTE: `onRequest` is working fine as expected, so variables and project ids are appropriately set too.

So what I'm doing wrong calling the callable `onCall` function?

> After adding more `console.logs`, found out no data is passed

```
Undefined
Undefined
Undefined
```

Comment: Can you share minimal reproducible steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [doc for Callable Cloud Functions 2nd generation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd) the arguments passed to the callback function have changed from

**1st gen:** `functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {...});`

to

**2nd gen:** `onCall((request) => {...});`.

---

So you need to do:

```js
exports.onLoginAddOTPEntry = onCall((request) => {

  const data = request.data;

  if (!data || !data.email || !data.otp) {
        throw new HttpsError("invalid-argument",
            "onLoginAddOTPEntry should be called with email and otp");
  }
    
  if (!request.auth) {
        throw new HttpsError(
            "unauthorized",
            "User is not authenticated",
        );
  }

  return "Worked!";
});
```

Comment: My bad! Thanks a lot, it is fixed! I was struggling to find the issue for a long time, as most examples and help over the internet are still in 1st gen!